# Subtract array of objects from array of objects

Tags: javascript

I know similar questions have been posted but they never seems to target the same problem.

I want to remove Objects contained in the second array (`itemsToRemove`) from the first array (`allItems`).

```
allItems = [{x:1, y:2}, {x:1, y:1}, {x:4, y:1}]

itemsToRemove = [{x:1, y:2}]

result = [{x:1, y:1}, {x:4, y:1}]
```

I've tried many ways, but it somehow fails at the `find()` condition

```
      const result = allItems.filter((itemFromAllItems ) => {
                return !itemsToRemove.find( itemToRemove => {
                    return itemFromAllItems.x === itemToRemove.x && itemFromAllItems.y === itemToRemove.y
                })
            })
```

Comment: You can not compare objects.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript

Comment: i am comparing 2 objects property x and y (updated)

Comment: Well you are now with that edit

Comment: can anyone please look at my answer and downvoting it with explanation of why it is wrong !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your objects only have x and y values, This will work.

```js
var allItems = [{x:1, y:2}, {x:1, y:1}, {x:4, y:1}]

var itemsToRemove = [{x:1, y:2}]

var result = allItems.filter(e => !itemsToRemove.some(s => s.x === e.x && s.y === e.y));

console.log(result);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Assuming they want to code. What would be a generic solution?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to make this dynamic

Comment: You can just replace `result` with `allItems` if you want `allItems` to be changed. E.g. `var allItems = allItems.filter(e => !itemsToRemove.some(s => s.x === e.x && s.y === e.y));`

Comment: @Philx94 Sorry, I didn't get you. Could you please explain?

Comment: Sorry, I'm having a hard time figuring why it is not working on my end. I'll be back.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to filter you can use `filter` and `some` to get the data you want however if you want to literally remove the object from the array you can use this instead

```js
allItems = [{x:1, y:2}, {x:1, y:1}, {x:4, y:1},{x:4, y:1},{x:4, y:1}]
itemsToRemove = [{x:1, y:2},{x:4, y:1}]
 for(let i=0;i<allItems.length;i++){
   o=allItems[i]
  itemsToRemove.some(v=>{if(o.x==v.x &&o.y==v.y) allItems.splice(i,1),i--})
 }
console.log(allItems)
```

Comment: Why is the downvote!!! why??? what is wrong with this response please I am interested to know, I am addressing the person who downvoted the answer, I am open to criticism show me what is the problem with this answer

Comment: Please remember before downvoting an answer that the auther made some effort to write an answer and unless the answer is very poor and bad or out of context it makes no sense to downvote it without at least providing an explanation

Comment: When I test this, I'm only getting this as a result:  0: Object { x: 1, y: 1 }

Comment: Yes because i used a different example (data) from the one used above, i added more data to stress the fact that this solution works even for same objects

Comment: @baumli You can test the code with the data provided above and it works as well

Comment: So you should have payed more attention and **read**  the code very well before downvoting an answer

Comment: I didn't downvote, was just testing the code.  I see that with your arrays it does indeed function as it should.  I suspect that the downvote may be the result of them not seeing the arrays were different as well.  Upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

This takes the 2 arrays, compares the values, and makes a new one with only the results that don't match.

```
<script>
allItems = [{x:1, y:2}, {x:1, y:1}, {x:4, y:1}];
itemsToRemove = [{x:1, y:2}]
result = [];
for(var i = 0; i < allItems.length; i++){
  for(var j = 0; j < itemsToRemove.length; j++){ 
    if(JSON.stringify(allItems[i]) !== JSON.stringify(itemsToRemove[j])){
      result.push(allItems[i]);
    }
  }
} 
console.log(result);
</script>
```